# Explaining why a complex integral is equal to 0

Tags: complex-analysis

> **Question:**
> $$f(z)= \frac{4z}{z^2-1}$$
>
> It has singularities at $z_0=1 \ \text{and} \ z_0 = -1$ with $\operatorname{Res}(f,1)=2  \ \text{and} \operatorname{Res}(f,-1)=2$
>
> Explain why $$\int_{-2}^2 f(it) \ dt =0$$

**My attempt:**

This past paper question is only worth one mark therefore it must be something simple that I am missing but I cannot see it.

Comment: Sorry, what does this lead to? Would this imply symmetry across the x axis and therefore 0 to 2 cancels with -2 to 0?

Comment: Just expand the expression and get
$$f(it) = -4i\frac{t}{t^2+1}$$
this is an odd function without any singularities for $t \in \mathbb{R}.$